# Restore button text in fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have fragment witch contains button. Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filters_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_open_filters"
        style="@style/no_elevation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_search_menu"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tv_padding_top_search_menu"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/et_padding_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/et_padding_left"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tv_padding_top_search_menu"
        android:text="@string/button_searchname_all"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_white_pressed_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_filter"
        style="@style/no_elevation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_search_menu"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tv_padding_top_search_menu"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tv_padding_top_search_menu"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_button_filters" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_clear_filter"
        style="@style/no_elevation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_search_menu"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tv_padding_top_search_menu"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tv_padding_top_search_menu"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_button_reset_filters"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So `button_open_filters` has dynamically change text. In fragment I have:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
  if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    //some code
  } else {
    //restore prevous state
  }
  return view;
}
```

But in debug mode I see that `savedInstanceState` has no state for button:

> android:view_state={2131624078=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4191c450}

So my question what I'm doing wrong? State for button is not saved by Android, for example I too have `Textview` that state was saved and properly restored by Android. I have implemented `onSaveInstance` in fragment.

Comment: you can try implement this methods: [android onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: Yes I resolved that by implemeting onSaveInstanceState method where I save text fro button and in onCreateView where I check that savedInstaceState is not null when i set text for button, but my question is why Android not save state for button itself ? Example when i switch button to TextView, then Android save state and restore text itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods in Fragment.

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("BUTTON_TEXT", "Press Me");
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String btnText = savedInstanceState.getString("BUTTON_TEXT");
    btn.setText("" + btnText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I resolved that by implemeting onSaveInstanceState method where I save text fro button and in onCreateView where I check that savedInstaceState is not null when i set text for button, but my question is why Android not save state for button itself ?